# Where to format numbers in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, number-formatting

Should I format my numbers `1234.20 => 1'234.20` in model or in the view using php and codeigniter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It belongs to the view layer.
The model only cares about the value, not how you present it to the user. Also, you may need to display it differently, if your site is multilingual.

Comment: well yes it is multilingual, but the language stuff is not handled by different templates. shell i use a pattern for sprintf() which depends on the language? and put a sprintf() in my view?

Comment: @helle Use the [`NumberFormatter`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php), which is locale-aware.

Answer (score 3):

In the view, since the transformation is presentational in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I would format it in the view, because this sperates the visual from the rest.